Read Aloud in Microsoft Word does not launch
In Microsoft Word, on the Review ribbon, clicking the 'Read Aloud' button does not open the Read Aloud controls or start the TTS.
System is running Windows 11 with up-to-date MSFT updates, office is 365 apps for business licensed, and is up to date. The Windows Speech library is correctly set to match OS and Office language.
With a document open, using Windows Narrator does do TTS. In word, using the 'Speak' command does TTS the highlighted word or passage. Read Aloud works in OUtlook, as well as in Word when Word is run in safe mode.
Office has been uninstalled and MSFT provide office clean uninstaller run, with office being reinstalled. DISM and SFC have also been run on the device, and up to date AV is installed and running.

Is this on a personal or corporate system?

"as well as in Word when Word is run in safe mode.", if so, have you tried to uncheck the COM add-ins in Word?

Yes, all COM add ins disabled, not an AD joined machine so no GPOs

Turns out the issue was a macro loaded to the normal.dotm that was bound to the same key combination as launching linked-in
